# Resources on gas cost for particular actions in Solidity

Tags: solidity, gas, mapping

Is there a good resource on Solidity gas costs, for instance the cost for a single read on a mapping (example code below)?

```
mapping (uint256 => bool) private table;

bool output = table[42];
```

I have the [OPCODE spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/view), and of course `estimateGas` exists, but I want to get a more intuitive feel for the cost of things, like reading from or writing to a variable or map.

In the latter case, I'd also love resources on the time complexity of maps, which I imagine has a bearing on cost (for instance, if access is `O(1)` and insertion is `O(n)`, then I assume gas cost for insertion scales with `n`).

Comment: Hi there. Just a quick comment about your final paragraph: I'm pretty sure that mappings are essentially perfect hash tables with constant worst-case access time and no collisions, so insertions are `O(1)`.